# Laravel passport: Manually create access token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, vue.js, vuejs2, single-page-application

I'm building an SPA using VueJS and Laravel.

I'm using Laravel passport for logins which works fine.

However I would like the ability to send users magic links to log in with. However I'm not sure how to create an access token without sending a request with the password to the oauth route.

It seems like it should be really easy to do, just inserting the right rows into `oauth_access_tokens` and `oauth_refresh_tokens`.

But i've been trawling through the code in the Passport repo and Google results and everything seems way more complicated.

What I would like is be able to do something like this:

```
$user = User::findFromMagicLink($link);
$token = $user->createAccessToken();
return response()->json(['access_token' => $token->token, 'refresh_token' => $token->refresh_token])
```

I'm guessing that's not possible otherwise it would be documented somewhere. But if it's something more complicated than that I can't figure it out.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this You can create access token like

```
$user = User::findFromMagicLink($link)
$token  = $user->createToken('UserToken', ['*']);
//or directly access
$token  = $user->createToken('UserToken', ['*'])->accessToken;
```

For more info Read: [Manage personal access token](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport#managing-personal-access-tokens)

Comment: Edit: sorry I misunderstood something. Will comment back once i've checked again.

Comment: You can read here: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/71 you can create your custom method but that is not good way

Comment: Thanks that seems to have actually worked perfectly!

Comment: How bout a refresh token? How to create that manually?